# I need two windows on the same file but screen too small for split

Tags: vim-windows

I'd like to modify a file at two different places but without having to go from one location to another in the same file. So I learned about windows but it seems they only work by splitting.
My screen is too small for working comfortably with a split screen.
Is there a way to have two windows on the same file and navigate from one to the other like I navigate buffers ?

If it's not possible, what solution do you recommend ? (Apart from moving one of the function to a different file)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might be interested in tabbed windows `:help tab-page`  That would let you open the same file in two separate views and flip back and forth between them.  `gt` would let you switch back and forth between the two tabs.

Comment: You could also try marks for your use case.

Comment: @Wolf please make that an answer

Comment: @AndrewHo-Lee please make that an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim supports tab views where each tab takes up all of Vim's usable space and you can quickly switch between them.  A tab page can be divided into windows, though it sounds like that's exactly what you *don't* want.  There are many tab-related commands.  You can learn about them at `:help tab-page`. On my system I was able to open a second view onto my current buffer by issuing the command `:tabnew %`.  Switching between tabs is as easy as <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> to go to the next tab, and <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to go to the previous tab.  If they are views onto the same buffer they will both reflect changes there immediately no matter which tab you are doing the editing in.  You can scroll them to two different places.  Each tab has its own cursor position, but they share marks.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use marks.  Marks are a way of remembering a position within a file.

To set a mark in a file, use <kbd>m</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> to set mark `a`.  To jump back to that mark, use <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> to jump to that line, or <kbd>`</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> to jump to that precise position.  The lowercase marks `a-z` are per-file and only remembered as long as that file is in the buffer list.  The uppercase marks `A-Z` are saved in `viminfo` thus persist between sessions and are global (for example, I have mark `V` set to the first line of my `vimrc` and so <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> will take me there and open the file if it isn't already in the buffer list).

For more information: [`:h mark-motions`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#mark-motions)